# как удалить все после определенного символа

Tags: python, текст

допустим у меня есть ссылка `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/646692326990807066/99a6fd86126fa657a0949fe1b2b42185.webp?size=1024`
мне надо удалить все после последней точки чтобы осталось только
`https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/646692326990807066/99a6fd86126fa657a0949fe1b2b42185`

я уже пробовал свой код, но он не работает

```
url = str(userID.avatar_url)
counter = 0
for i in url:
    if i == '.':
        counter += 1
counter -= 1
print(counter)
url.split(".", '')[counter]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/646692326990807066/99a6fd86126fa657a0949fe1b2b42185.webp?size=1024'

url, *_ = url.rpartition('.')
```

---

```py
import re
url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/646692326990807066/99a6fd86126fa657a0949fe1b2b42185.webp?size=1024'

url = re.sub(r'\.[^./]+?$', '', url)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
url = re.match('(https?://.+/.*?)([.?]?$)',url).group(1)
```

`.+` - жадный + до последнего слеша.

`.*?` - ленивая * до точки или вопроса или конца строки

проблемы с точкой в домене нет

Answer (score 1):

```
url = url[:url.rfind('.')]
```

Но это будет работать корректно только если точка точно есть.
Иначе удалит точку из доменного имени.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод `rfind` для поиска последней точки и срезы (slicing) для удаления части строки после нее. Вот пример кода:

```
link = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/646692326990807066/99a6fd86126fa657a0949fe1b2b42185.webp?size=1024"
last_dot_index = link.rfind(".")
if last_dot_index != -1:  # если точка найдена
    link = link[:last_dot_index]  # обрезаем строку до последней точки
print(link)  # выводим обновленную ссылку
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: теперь я узнал о rfind